# Guide to solving Harary's exercises

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Most of Harary's harder exercises are research problems (although solved), that need almost always a single key idea as a breakthrough. Often it so happens that even after thinking for a long time no solution comes to mind.

I am a beginner in Graph Theory. How should I solve the problems from Harary? Often what I do is, I have no option other than looking up the original paper where the solution was published, get some idea on how to start, and then sometimes I am able to complete the proof.

For example, I am stuck for some time on this problem:

> If a graph has diameter $d$ and girth $2d+1$ then it is regular.

This also was a research problem solved. I think Harary should have given some hints on solving the harder problems.

What I know is, for any simple graph, if $D$ is the diameter, then the girth $\leq 2D+1$. But what happens when there is equality? I tried to start with vertices $u$ and $v$, with $deg(u)>deg(v)$ and whether $u$ is connected to the cycle, or $v$ is connected to $u$, etc. There are so many things at once!

Could someone please give me a hint only to start? I haven't seen the solution to this problem and have been trying it. However, I am convinced that the way problems have been solved, I could never have done them. All I would have spent are fruitless months.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choose vertices $a$ and $u$ at maximum distance. There is one neighbor of $a$ at distance $D-1$ from $u$. What is the distance from $u$ of the other neighbors? Working from here, that $a$ and $v$ have the same valency.

Now consider a cycle of length $2D+1$, and prove that all vertices on it have the same valency.

To be fair to Harary, this is a reasonable problem for a graduate course, although hard to get started on.

Comment: How did "you" get started on? Please share with me how you could "see" the technique.

Comment: @Landon Carter: Your question is too general to be answered well in a comment. I would start by trying to prove it the case $D=2$. A second strategy is that if I am trying to prove a graph is regular, I would usually try to prove that adjacent vertices have the same valency. That probably doesn't work here, but since diameter is involved, it might lead you to look at vertices at maximum distance.

Comment: I actually spent quite some time trying to show adjacent vertices have maximum valency. I even thought of showing first that maximum separated points on the cycle have same valency.

Comment: @Landon Carter: generally students are brought up on problems that require one key idea to solve. In the real world, problems are not always so nicely packaged.

Answer (score 1):

In case that you need a complete proof, see the following article.

Singleton, Robert R. (1968), "There is no irregular Moore graph", American Mathematical Monthly 75 (1): 42–43